# jQuery: focus()

Tags: jquery, focus, fancybox

I have a fancybox that ajax calls file.php to get the content to show. file.php contains:

```
<SCRIPT>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('[name=replyMsg]').focus();
});
</SCRIPT>
```

but still it wont focus on the element when the box opens.

How can I fix this/any solution?

My fancybox settings looks like this:

```
    $("a.fancybox_wallConv").each(function(){
       $(this).fancybox({
        titleShow     : false,
        width:    380,
        height:   190,
        autoDimensions: false,
        overlayOpacity: 0.3, 
 showNavArrows: false,
centerOnScroll: true,
        href: "file.php"
      }); 
    });
```

I am using the href function for the ajax call.

http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to call focus() before the fancybox appears. Instead of putting that call in `ready()`, put it in `onComplete()`.

```
   $("a.fancybox_wallConv").each(function(){
       $(this).fancybox({
        titleShow     : false,
        width:    380,
        height:   190,
        autoDimensions: false,
        overlayOpacity: 0.3, 
        showNavArrows: false,
        centerOnScroll: true,
        href: "file.php",
        onComplete: function() { $('[name=replyMsg]').focus(); }
      }); 
    });
```